# Mock SqlException with specific Numer

Tags: c#, moq

I'm trying to write a unit test which has to throw a specific SqlException with Number 1205 or 1222. After fallowing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6075100/15992166) (because SqlException is sealed) now I have to use reflection to set the Number property which is read only.
I've tried using Mono.reflection but using the fallowing code I get an exception:

```
typeof(SqlException).GetProperty("Number").GetBackingField()
            .SetValue(exception, SqlDeadlockViolation);
Exception: "Value does not fall within the expected range."
```

Any idea on how I can set the Numer property?

Comment: Maybe look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976996/moq-and-throwing-a-sqlexception

Comment: It sure does. Thank you. Though the constructor signature may change over time and you'll need to patch the code. I was wondering why it's not possible to get the backing field of the Number property ?