# Mocking the throwing of exceptions with Microsoft Moles

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, mocking, moles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to throw a SqlException(need for mocking)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386962/how-to-throw-a-sqlexceptionneed-for-mocking)

I want to mock the throwing of `SqlException` when `ExecuteNonQuery` is executed;

```
System.Data.SqlClient.Moles.MSqlCommand.AllInstances.ExecuteNonQuery =
            (command) =>
                {
                    throw new MSqlException();
                };
```

This doesn't work as the compiler complains `MSqlException` doesn't derive from `Exception`. Am I going about this the wrong way, will I need to wrap `ExecuteNonQuery` in my code to achieve this?

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386962/how-to-throw-a-sqlexceptionneed-for-mocking

Comment: Yeah I'd just found that. The response here solves this, you basically need to cast it;

http://stackoverflow.com/a/3795751/771698

Answer (score 0):

If you were to throw a `SqlException` I would expect this to work. It inherits from `DbException`, which inherits from `ExternalException`, which inherits from `ExternalException`.

If you write a custom exception (I am assuming `MSqlException` is one), you should still inherit from an exception class...

```
public class MSqlException: SqlException {
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was found in another question. The mole needs casting.

stackoverflow.com/a/3795751/771698